# Change random assignment to cyclical assignment SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

EXAMPLE:

The issue is that I have, for example, 5 people to solve 100 cases, and the assignment has to be fair, I think that SQL through loops should be able to assign the first cases to the first 5 people, but then it has to go back to count and reassign, in case a new case falls.

I have two tables with the following fields

Technicians

ID_TEC-----NOM_TEC-----LINEA_TEC

and other whit cases

ID_CASE----DESCRIPTION_CASE

The problem arises because I have to assign cases to each technician. The assignment must be cyclic, that is:

CASE1 TECH1

CASE2 TECH2

CASE3 TECH3

CASE4 TECH1 ...

and when you load the data in the table and rerun the SP or run the job that assigns them, go back to the table, re-count the values ​​and reassign them according to the last assigned TECn. I hope the description is clearer!

Comment: Please provide sample input and output data that would indicate your query is working correctly.

Comment: We can't see your data. So you will need to explain what "more activities than another" means in relational terms. Count of records in `USER_TBL`? Another table? A value from a column?

Comment: Currently, when I execute the query, it shows me the name of the user to whom the assignment will be made. For each new query, it shows me a new user in a random way

Comment: Are you saying you need to balance user workload when assigning task to users?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The idea is to assign tasks in a balanced way.

Comment: Several approaches could do: what @GordonLinoff offered, something about ROWNUMBER if this is one-time job (or periodical), to store and recompute statistics and availability of each user if this is needed online. Not clear what is your case.

Comment: The idea is that, if there are 700 tasks, those tasks will be distributed one by one among the 5 technicians. When you reach the last technician, you must go back to the first and continue assigning. This must be fulfilled until there are no more activities

Comment: @ArnellVasquezC tell more about user tables and the query that uses output of the query mentioned in question

Comment: This is the case, in my user table I have 7 users, for example. The Select that I want to make should consult those users and show, for each query, a user. But, do not show them randomly, if not, taking into account the user that was previously selected and show the next one. When it reaches user 7 and the query is re-performed, it must now show user 1 again. I know a bit about Databases, but seeing it from another point, it's like having an array of 7 users and with a ForEach iterating over each user. The important thing is to show a single user in each call made

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the numbers 1-5 randomly to the tasks by doing:

```
select t.*,
       (1 + row_number() over (order by newid()) % 5) as user_assignment
from t
```